# Calculate some averages in .txt python

Tags: python, average

I have a `.txt`-file called `ecc.txt`. It contains more than 8000 lines of numbers. I want to count the average of every 360 lines in that file.
Here is the code:

```py
import math

f = open(r'ecc.txt').read()
data = []
for line in data:
    sum = 0
for i in range (len(data)):
    if i % 360 != 0:
        sum = sum + ecc[i]
    else:
        average = sum / 360
        print(average)
        sum = 0
```

When I am running it, nothing happens. I didn't get any results. The code just running and end without any result.

Is there something wrong with this code?
Thank you.

Comment: you're iterating over `data`, which is an empty list

Comment: You should consider using itertools.islice rather than reading the whole file into memory. You are probably going to want to convert that text into a number too.

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion. Yeah, I forgot to input f in the data. @ThomasJungblut

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion, you are right, I have a problem while convert text into a number, but it solved, thanks. @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
avg_dict = {}
with open('ecc.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split(' ')
    sum = 0
    i = 0
    for str_number in data:
       sum += int(str_number)
       i += 1
       if i % 360 == 0:
          avg_dict[i] = sum/360
          sum = 0
```

I've assumed that your file text has an empty space as separator. Otherwise, you can change the sep value in the split method. If there is not separator change data as:

```
data = list(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, the separator between data is the new row. Here is the example of the ,txt file
0.00002
0.0003
0.0004

I think, it should be split in another way.

Comment: It must be considered the separator between two consecutive values, in the example you reported it seems they are separated by a single tab "\t". I made an example for the code assuming values are separated as you reported, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You code would work with some changes:

```
import math

data=[]
with open(r'ecc.txt') as f:
    for i in f:
        data.append(int(i))
for line in data:
    sum = 0
for i in range (len(data)):
    if i%360 !=0:
        sum = sum + ecc[i]
    else:
        average = sum/360
        print(average)
        sum=0
```

Be aware though, that this code doesn't include values for each 360th element (i guess it's not a problem for an average) and also you don't have average for last elements